# MariaDB bind-address not updating?

Tags: 18.04, mysql, configuration, database, mariadb

I'm trying to set the `bind-address` of my MariaDB installation to `0.0.0.0` to allow external connections.

I edited `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and updated the `[mysqld]` section to the following:

```
[mysqld]
...
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
...
```

After running `sudo service mariadb restart`, I still wasn't able to connect from external sources. I'm able to confirm that the `bind-address` wasn't updated by running `mysqld --print-defaults`. The output is below, you might have to horizonally scroll a little to see the bolded argument.

```
mysqld would have been started with the following arguments:
--user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306 --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp --lc-messages-dir=/usr/share/mysql --skip-external-locking --bind-address=127.0.0.1 --key_buffer_size=16M --max_allowed_packet=16M --thread_stack=192K --thread_cache_size=8 --myisam_recover_options=BACKUP --query_cache_limit=1M --query_cache_size=16M --log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log --expire_logs_days=10 --max_binlog_size=100M --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

How can I properly update the `bind-address`?

Answer (score 3):

So, it turns out I was editing the wrong configuration file. After running `strace mysqld --print-defaults` I found it opening a different file.

Updating the `bind-address` in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` changed the option correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Also noteworthy: `mariadb.cnf` sources both `conf.d` and `mariadb.conf.d` directories. I was wondering why I just couldn't get rid of the `bind-address=127.0.0.1` option.

It was because I made the backup `original.50-server.cnf`, which still was read.

Comment: My life saver. thx! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you comment out (#) line in your .conf file.

```
# !includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d 
# !includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

The parameters from your .conf file will not be overwritten from 50-server.cnf and others.